# Implement SearchView in Action Bar in Android

Tags: android, searchview, android-searchmanager

I have implemented search in action bar, but I am getting 0 results always, even though the text is available. Not sure where I am going wrong?

Here is my piece of code that I have tried:

```
    ArrayList<States> stateList = new ArrayList<States>();

    States _states = new States("AP","Andhra Pradesh",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("DL","Delhi",true);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("GA","Goa",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("JK","Jammu & Kashmir",true);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("KA","Karnataka",true);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("KL","Kerala",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("RJ","Rajasthan",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("WB","West Bengal",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("AP","Andhra Pradesh",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("DL","Delhi",true);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("GA","Goa",false);

    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.state_info, stateList);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

My Search option in Actionbar:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService( Context.SEARCH_SERVICE );
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search).getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    //searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) 
{
    // this is your adapter that will be filtered
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText))
    {
        listView.clearTextFilter();
    }
    else
    {
        listView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
    }

    return true;
}
```

MyCustom Adaptor:

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<States>
{

    private ArrayList<States> stateList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 

            ArrayList<States> stateList) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, stateList);
        this.stateList = new ArrayList<States>();
        this.stateList.addAll(stateList);
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView code;
        CheckBox name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null)
        {

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.state_info, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v)  
                {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    States _state = (States) cb.getTag();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is " + cb.isChecked(), 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    _state.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });

        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        States state = stateList.get(position);

        holder.code.setText(" (" + state.getCode() + ")");
        holder.name.setText(state.getName());
        holder.name.setChecked(state.isSelected());

        holder.name.setTag(state);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implements a filter in your custom adapter. Try this: [Android Action Bar Search: How to filter a list by the property of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546412/android-action-bar-search-how-to-filter-a-list-by-the-property-of-a-list-item/24546820#24546820)

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: @Alejandra: Thanks for the quick reply. I have seen this but couldn't understand the last few lines: for (Object obj : listaTotal) - what is listaTotal here?
     {
      if (condition)
      {
                         listResult.add(obj);
                     }
                 }

Comment: @TheDevMan listaTotal is where you have all the objects to compare. For example, listaTotal has all the user and in condition you can compare user.getNombre().equals(string) and if the condition is true you add the user to filter list. I do not know if I explained. Sorry for my poor English

Comment: @Alejandra: Sorry but I am still getting an NPE in listofTotal? Here is my code of line: http://txs.io/wfqb Am I missing something in the code?, What is listaTotal? An Array of obj?

Comment: @TheDevMan listaTotal would be stateList. Do you want filter elements of stateList?

Comment: Thanks a lot I got working. I had to change a few things to suit my needs.